# Trouble with inner class, toString confliction

Tags: java, tostring, inner-classes

Based on one of the Head First books examples I'm having a little trouble in which the toString method is causing issues with my student and they're uni and home address being outputted correctly. All i'm trying to do is output if a students uni address is empty use his home address else use the uni one.

But my test data looks like the following

> John John72 Nottingham Drive
>
> John72 Nottingham Drive

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Student student1 = new Student("John", 19, "Walkers Way");
    student1.setUniAddress(72, "Nottingham Drive");
    System.out.print(student1.toString());
    }
}
```

Other Class

```
public class Student {
private String name;
private Address homeAddress, uniAddress;

public Student(String name, int houseNumber, String homeStreet){
    this.name = name;
    this.homeAddress = new Address(houseNumber, homeStreet);
}



public String getName() { return this.name; }
public Address getHomeAddress(){
    if(this.uniAddress == null){
        return this.homeAddress;
    }else{
        return getUniAddress();//this.uniAddress;
    }
}
    
public Address getUniAddress() { return this.uniAddress; }
public void setUniAddress(int number, String add){
    Address address = new Address(number, add);
    uniAddress = address;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return getName() + " " + getHomeAddress() + " " + getUniAddress() + "\n";
}

public class Address{
    private int number;
    private String street;
    public Address(int no, String street){
        this.number = no;
        this.street = street;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return name + number + " " + street + "\n";
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `getHomeAddress` method takes care of displaying the uni address, so this line:

```
return getName() + " " + getHomeAddress() + " " + getUniAddress() + "\n";
```

can be shortened to:

```
return getName() + " " + getHomeAddress() + " " + "\n";
```

Otherwise your `getHomeAddress` method will pull the uni address, then your `getUniAddress` method will pull the uni address again.

Also in your address `toString` you are pulling the person's name and you probably didn't mean to (and you might not want a newline here either since you have a newline in your other `toString` method).

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    return number + " " + street;
}
```

Comment: Also having `\n` in each toString() probably isn't desirable either.

Comment: Ah can't believe i didn't notice that, I guess that's what fresh eyes are for. Thank you.